Flutter CallKit Incoming - Accept Call Not Working When App is Terminated
I am developing a calling app using Flutter, and I am utilizing the flutter_callkit_incoming package for handling incoming call notifications. The notifications and the acceptCall event work perfectly when the app is open or running in the background. When I click the "Accept" button, it properly navigates to the calling screen.
However, I encounter an issue when the app is terminated. The notification still appears, but clicking the "Accept" button does not work as expected.

Try this: https://medium.com/@Ayush_b58/flutter-callkit-handle-actions-in-the-killed-state-e6f296c603e6

Have you added a listener? Like this?
  static void setupCallkitHander() {
    bool mute = false;
    FlutterCallkitIncoming.onEvent.listen((CallEvent? event) async {
      switch (event!.event) {
        case Event.actionCallIncoming:
          // TODO: received an incoming call
          break;
        case Event.actionCallStart:
          // TODO: started an outgoing call
          // TODO: show screen calling in Flutter
          break;
        case Event.actionCallAccept:
          // TODO: show screen calling in Flutter
          // does not work for android in terminated state
          final activeCall = await IncomingCallHelper.getIncomingActiveCall();
          if (activeCall != null) {
            logger.d('Navigating to callRoute');
            getIt<AppRouter>().navigate(
              AgoraCallRoute(callData: activeCall.callData),
            );
          }
          break;
        case Event.actionCallDecline:
          // TODO: declined an incoming call
          break;
        case Event.actionCallEnded:
          AgoraAvCallController.instance.endCall();
          break;
        case Event.actionCallTimeout:
          // TODO: missed an incoming call
          break;
        case Event.actionCallCallback:
          // TODO: only Android - click action `Call back` from missed call notification
          break;
        case Event.actionCallToggleHold:
          // TODO: only iOS
          break;
        case Event.actionCallToggleMute:
          // only iOS
          if (mute) {
            AgoraAvCallController.instance.unMuteLocalAudio();
            mute = false;
          } else {
            AgoraAvCallController.instance.muteLocalAudio();
            mute = true;
          }
          break;
        case Event.actionCallToggleDmtf:
          // TODO: only iOS
          break;
        case Event.actionCallToggleGroup:
          // TODO: only iOS
          break;
        case Event.actionCallToggleAudioSession:
          // TODO: only iOS
          break;
        case Event.actionDidUpdateDevicePushTokenVoip:
          // TODO: only iOS
          break;
        case Event.actionCallCustom:
          // TODO: for custom action
          break;
      }
    });
  }


ok the problem you are facing is callkit accept callback doesn't support yet but one workaround of it is You can direactly call or listen its event by creating a saperate listener for it
inside _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(){}
when certain condition met user
if (messageData['notificationType'] == 1) {
  CallUtils.showIncomingCall(messageData);
  initforbackground();
}

and create a Saperate CallUtils class
   class CallUtils {
   static Future<void> showIncomingCall(var body) async {
   Uuid uuid = const Uuid();
   String currentUuid = uuid.v4();

String defaultImage = 'https://i.pravatar.cc/500';
String? profilePic = body['profile'];

String imageUrl;
if (profilePic != null) {
  imageUrl = imgBaseurl + profilePic;
} else {
  imageUrl = defaultImage;
}
bool calltype = body['call_type'] == 10; //11 video call or 10 audio call

log('calltype is  $calltype');
log('imageUrl is  $imageUrl');
log('imageUrl is  ${body['name']}');
log('fcmToken is  ${body['fcmToken']}');

CallKitParams callKitParams = CallKitParams(
  id: currentUuid,
  nameCaller: body['astrologerName'] ?? 'Astrologer',
  appName: 'Astroway',
  handle: 'Astroway Partner',
  type: calltype ? 0 : 1, // 0 for audio call, 1 for video call
  textAccept: 'Accept',
  textDecline: 'Decline',
  duration: 30000,
  missedCallNotification: const NotificationParams(
    showNotification: true,
    isShowCallback: true,
    subtitle: 'Missed call',
    callbackText: 'Call back',
  ),
  extra: <String, dynamic>{
    'astrologerId': body['astrologerId'],
    'astrologerName': body['astrologerName'],
    'call_type': body['call_type'],
    'channelName': body['channelName'],
    'callId': body['callId'],
    'profile': body['profile'],
    'token': body['token'],
    'fcmToken': body['fcmToken'],
    'call_duration': body['call_duration'],
  },
  headers: <String, dynamic>{'apiKey': 'sunil@123!', 'platform': 'flutter'},
  android: const AndroidParams(
    isCustomNotification: true,
    isShowLogo: false,
    ringtonePath: 'system_ringtone_default',
    backgroundColor: '#0955fa',
    actionColor: '#4CAF50',
    textColor: '#ffffff',
    incomingCallNotificationChannelName: "Incoming Call 1",
    isShowCallID: true, //for showing handle in incoming call notification
  ),
  ios: IOSParams(
    iconName: 'CallKitLogo',
    handleType: 'generic',
    supportsVideo: true,
    maximumCallGroups: 2,
    maximumCallsPerCallGroup: 1,
    audioSessionMode: 'default',
    audioSessionActive: true,
    audioSessionPreferredSampleRate: 44100.0,
    audioSessionPreferredIOBufferDuration: 0.005,
    supportsDTMF: true,
    supportsHolding: true,
    supportsGrouping: false,
    supportsUngrouping: false,
    ringtonePath: 'system_ringtone_default',
  ),
);

await FlutterCallkitIncoming.showCallkitIncoming(callKitParams);

}
}
and this is my saperate listner for listning only in background So i am here is catching and saving accept/decline event and saved them in sharedprefrences
void initforbackground() async {
   final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

FlutterCallkitIncoming.onEvent.listen((CallEvent? event) async {
if (event == null) {
  await prefs.setBool('is_accepted', false);
  await prefs.setBool('is_rejected', false);

  return;
}

switch (event.event) {
  case Event.actionCallStart:
    // Handle call accept action
    print('actionCallStart call incoming');
    break;
  case Event.actionCallAccept:
    // Handle call decline action
    print('actionCallAccept call incoming');
    await prefs.setBool('is_accepted', true);
    String extraDataJson = jsonEncode(event.body['extra']);
    print('actionCallAccept extraDataJson $extraDataJson');
    await prefs.setString('is_accepted_data', extraDataJson);

    break;
  case Event.actionCallDecline:
    print('call rejected');
    // Handle call end action
    await chatController.rejectedChat(event.body['extra']['callId']);

    await prefs.setBool('is_rejected', true);
    await prefs.setBool('is_accepted', false);
    await prefs.setBool('is_rejected', false);
    await prefs.setString('is_accepted_data', '');

    break;
  case Event.actionCallCallback:
    print('actionCallCallback initforbackground call incoming click');

    break;

  case Event.actionCallTimeout:
    print('actionCallTimeout initforbackground call incoming click');
    //clear background data when missed call so whenever app open agian then this data
    //not open direactly callscreens
    await prefs.setBool('is_accepted', false);
    await prefs.setBool('is_rejected', false);
    await prefs.setString('is_accepted_data', '');
    break;

  default:
    break;
}
});
  }

and again remember to clear incoming call data when accepted or when call missed so next time when app is opened it didn't   executed
and my normal event listner which i am calling from main.dart
initstate is different
 @override
 void initState() { 
    super.initState();
   initializeCallKitEventHandlers();
  }

and
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
 void initializeCallKitEventHandlers() {
  FlutterCallkitIncoming.onEvent.listen((CallEvent? event) async {
  if (event == null) return;
  switch (event.event) {
    case Event.actionCallStart:
      print('actionCallStart call incoming');
     break;
  case Event.actionCallAccept:
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    print('actionCallAccept call incoming');
    await prefs.setBool('is_accepted', false);
    await prefs.setString('is_accepted_data', '');

    callAccept(event);
    break;
  case Event.actionCallDecline:
    // Handle call end action

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool('is_accepted', false);
    await prefs.setString('is_accepted_data', '');

    global.callOnFcmApiSendPushNotifications(
        fcmTokem: [event.body['extra']["fcmToken"]],
        title: 'End chat from customer');
    callController.update();
    await chatController
        .rejectedChat(event.body['extra']["callId"].toString());
    callController.update();

    print('call rejected');
    await chatController.rejectedChat(event.body['extra']['callId']);

    break;
  case Event.actionCallCallback:
    print('actionCallCallback call incoming click');
    callAccept(event);
    break;
  case Event.actionCallIncoming:
    print('actionCallIncoming call incoming click');

  case Event.actionCallCustom:
    print('actionCallIncoming call incoming click');

    break;
  default:
    break;
}
   });
    }

Now you can check sharepref save data and in splashscreen or after that when app is fully opened do Your needed work
call this method in splashscreen and use it
  Future<void> _loadSavedData() async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

bool? isacceptedcall = await prefs.getBool('is_accepted');
print('is accepted or not $isacceptedcall');
if (isacceptedcall == true) {
  // Handle call end action
  String? dataaccepted = await prefs.getString('is_accepted_data');
  if (dataaccepted!.isNotEmpty) {
    await prefs.setBool('is_accepted', false);
    print('is accepted dataaccepted $dataaccepted}');
    callAccept(jsonDecode(dataaccepted));
    await prefs.setString('is_accepted_data', '');
  }
}

bool? isrejectedcall = await prefs.getBool('is_rejected');
if (isrejectedcall == true) {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setBool('is_accepted', false);
  await prefs.setString('is_accepted_data', '');
}
}

and finally call your needed screens
 void callAccept(Map<String, dynamic> extraData) async {
  print('extra call astrologerId ${extraData['astrologerId']}');

  final callController = Get.find<CallController>();
if (extraData['call_type'] == 10) {
   await callController.acceptedCall(extraData["callId"]);
Get.to(
  () => AcceptCallScreen(
    astrologerId: extraData["astrologerId"],
    astrologerName: extraData["astrologerName"] == null
        ? "Astrologer"
        : extraData["astrologerName"],
    astrologerProfile:
        extraData["profile"] == null ? "" : extraData["profile"],
    token: extraData["token"],
    callChannel: extraData["channelName"],
    callId: extraData["callId"],
    duration: extraData['call_duration'].toString(),
  ),
);
  } else if (extraData['call_type'] == 11) {
     Get.to(() => OneToOneLiveScreen(
      channelname: extraData["channelName"],
      callId: extraData["callId"],
      fcmToken: extraData["token"].toString(),
      end_time: extraData['call_duration'].toString(),
    ));
  }
  }


Write your listener in the firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler method; it will work. Then save your payload in Shared Preference and handle it in the dashboard screen to navigate in the call screen.
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    // Listen for incoming call events
    FlutterCallkitIncoming.onEvent.listen((CallEvent? event) async {
        switch (event!.event) {
            case Event.actionCallIncoming:
                // TODO: received an incoming call
                break;
            case Event.actionCallStart:
                // TODO: started an outgoing call
                // TODO: show screen calling in Flutter
                break;
            case Event.actionCallAccept:
                // TODO: show screen calling in Flutter
                // Does not work for Android in terminated state
                final activeCall = await IncomingCallHelper.getIncomingActiveCall();
                if (activeCall != null) {
                    logger.d('Navigating to callRoute');
                    getIt<AppRouter>().navigate(
                        AgoraCallRoute(callData: activeCall.callData),
                    );
                }
                break;
            case Event.actionCallDecline:
                // TODO: declined an incoming call
                break;
            case Event.actionCallEnded:
                // End the call
                AgoraAvCallController.instance.endCall();
                break;
            case Event.actionCallTimeout:
                // TODO: missed an incoming call
                break;
            case Event.actionCallCallback:
                // TODO: only Android - click action `Call back` from missed call notification
                break;
            case Event.actionCallToggleHold:
                // TODO: only iOS
                break;
            case Event.actionCallToggleMute:
                // Only iOS - mute or unmute the local audio
                if (mute) {
                    AgoraAvCallController.instance.unMuteLocalAudio();
                    mute = false;
                } else {
                    AgoraAvCallController.instance.muteLocalAudio();
                    mute = true;
                }
                break;
            case Event.actionCallToggleDmtf:
                // TODO: only iOS
                break;
            case Event.actionCallToggleGroup:
                // TODO: only iOS
                break;
            case Event.actionCallToggleAudioSession:
                // TODO: only iOS
                break;
            case Event.actionDidUpdateDevicePushTokenVoip:
                // TODO: only iOS
                break;
            case Event.actionCallCustom:
                // TODO: for custom action
                break;
        }
    });
}

